# Using a dropdown menu in a form for a SELECT statement with SQL

Tags: php, sql, html

Thank you for reading my question.

I am building a form that will let users search a db for cards used in a collectible card game. I want to include a dropdown menu that will let users narrow their search down to a specific card expansion.

Here is my dropdown menu:

```
<select name="Expsn" onchange="this.submit()">
     <option>All Expansions</option>
     <option value="Core">Core</option>
     <option value="SoM">Shadows of Mirkwood</option>
```

And here is the select statement:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM carddb 
WHERE Expsn ='" . $_POST['Expsn'] . "' AND Type='Hero' ";
```

This works well when selecting either Core or MoR, but if the dropbox is left blank "All Expansions" is passed into the $_POST['Expsn']. (I use echo $sql; to output the SELECT statement). How can I set up the default to return card from all expansions.

I have spent the last few weeks learning PHP and SQL online, so it is very possible that my whole approach here is VERY wrong and not scalable, so any 'big picture' help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If Expsn comes set, then add the condition to SQL, like:

```
$expsn = (strlen($_POST['Expsn']) > 0) ? "Expsn = '" . $_POST['Expsn'] . "' AND " : '';
$sql = "SELECT * FROM carddb WHERE $expsn Type='Hero'";
```

Comment: `if ($_POST['Expsn'] != "1") {$expsn = "Expsn='" . $_POST['Expsn'] . "' AND ";}
  else {$expsn = " ";}
 
 $sql = "SELECT * FROM carddb WHERE $expsn  Type='Hero' ";`

Comment: I hadn't thought to put variables inside the SELECT statement and then do a simple if statement on the variable. I changed the default option tag to:<option value="1">All Expansions</option>. I have several more things to add so I think this will scale a little better.

Comment: Great. For small ifs like that many times the ternary operator looks better: http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.ternary

Comment: Thank you all so much, this was the last piece of the puzzle I needed for this project!

Answer (score 3):

First change your "All Expansions" option to have an empty value:

```
<option value="">All Expansions</option>
```

This is so that you can change the wording later without having to update your PHP code.

```
if (empty($_POST['Expsn'])) {
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM carddb WHERE Type='Hero'";
} else {
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM carddb WHERE Expsn ='" . mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['Expsn']) . "' AND Type='Hero'";
}
```

The `mysql_real_escape_string` bit is really important to prevent SQL injection - I've assumed you're using the mysql extension here but there's equivalent functions for the other extensions.

Comment: This looks good, except I'm understanding that $_POST['Expsn'] isn't empty. The if statement should check if it equals "All Expansion", in which case it should ignore it.

Comment: Good catch @Will, updated the answer to correct that. I usually use value="" to avoid tying the processing to the presentation.

Comment: In that case, you really should have the form have a correct value attribute of empty string. <option value="">All Expansions</option>. That will avoid any ambiguity.

Comment: There are going to quite a few more other search options added so I need something that will be a little more scalable.

Comment: Thank you all so much, this was the last piece of the puzzle I needed for this project!

Comment: Thanks for mentioning SQL injection - despite being obvious, I hadn't even realized I needed to protect myself against such attack.

Answer (score 0):

just use this

```
<option value="*">All Expansions</option>
```